# How can I find out why vim keeps changing my expandtab setting

Tags: vim, janus

I use vim. Specifically I am using [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus). I have expandtab set. However, during the course of using vim, for some reason, my expandtab setting gets set to noexpandtab, and my files start to gain hard tabs. I have tried typing `:verbose set expandtab?` but this does not show me anything (specifically, it shows me that `noexpandtab` is set, but it doesn't show a file that is responsible for setting it).

So I would like to find out:

- Why my expandtab setting might be changing
- How I can track down the culprit and prevent it from happening

Thanks

Comment: What does your :verb set expandtab? show?

Comment: It just comes up with 'noexpandtab', i.e. no path to a file where it was set.

Comment: Reset your gvim and try again, first thing: :verb set expandtab? (don't forget the question mark).

Comment: Apart from that what does your :scriptnames show?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
:verb set expandtab?
:verb set et?
:verb set invexpandtab?
```

*expandtab* can really be set in a number of ways :/

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I didn't realise that running those different commands might produce different answers. Also, what does `invexpandtab` do? I couldn't find much on google.

Comment: @jonleighton - Just like any other invcommand, it toggles the state on/off. set invnumber, set invexpandtab, set inv... help invnumber.

Comment: Ok so I have tracked it down to the [align plugin](https://github.com/tsaleh/vim-align/blob/master/autoload/Align.vim#L484). `:verb set expandtab?` showed me - I think perhaps I forgot the question mark when I tried it in the past.

Comment: I think I'll try the tabular plugin as an alternative. (in the interim I've just deleted that line but that's quite hacky)

Comment: All these three commands do exactly the same thing. Vim attaches information about where `expandtab` is set to the `expandtab` option, not to a string used to set it.

Comment: I had this issue.  The cause was `set binary` in `~/.vimrc` which automatically sets `noexpandtab`.

Answer (score 6):

I should add that in addition to the above if you tried the following:

```
:verb set expandtab?
:verb set et?
:verb set invexpandtab?
```

And you get back with no line number or file:

```
noexpandtab
```

It's more than likely that you have the following and need to change the order:

```
set expandtab

set binary
set noeol
```

Change to (note the order)

```
set binary
set noeol

set expandtab
```

The reason for this is due to [set binary](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'binary') command has a few defaults it executes after it runs.  Including the following:

```
'textwidth'  will be set to 0
'wrapmargin' will be set to 0
'modeline'   will be off
'expandtab'  will be off
```

I noted DavidWinterbottom called this out in his comment, but that seemed to be the only comment that was hidden by default and this caused me to do a lot more reading that was necessary, so hopefully this post helps another poor soul from wasting countless hours tracking this down.

Answer (score 3):

VIM settings can either be set in a configuration file, or in a modeline inside the file you're editing. Note that `expandtab` can be shortened in VIM to `et`, so be sure to look for that as well.

Possible configuration files I'd look for:

1. `/etc/vim/vimrc` and other files in that directory (sometime `vimrc.local` and such)
2. `$HOME/.vimrc`

As for modelines, they are simply configuration options for VIM, located as comments in the file itself. If this only happens with some files but not others, look for comments that look something like:

```
/* vim: set noet ai tw=75: */
```

And try to remove them and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Grepping hasn't turned up much. I'm going to try ldigas when I next manage to repro the problem and see if that explains anything.