# Why does `set binary` reset `expandtab` property?

Tags: vim

In Vim, why does including `set binary` after `set expandtab` unset expandtab? I just had this issue for the first time, and here is a comment from another SO user in the past having the same problem: [How can I find out why vim keeps changing my expandtab setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903103/how-can-i-find-out-why-vim-keeps-changing-my-expandtab-setting#comment18826089_8903323)

Comment: Possibly because it just says so in the docs? http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'binary' and it would seem reasonable that when editing a file in binary mode you would not want character substitution of any kind to happen while you edit.

Comment: This cost me a .vimrc bijction :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because expanding tabs to spaces in the context of a binary file is almost always wrong:

1. Tabs may not represent whitespace at all; they may just be bytes which happen to be `\t`.  Expansion would alter the meaning.
2. The offsets into the file may need to be preserved, which `expandtab` does not do.
3. There is little actual benefit to any sort of automatic whitespace manipulation when editing binary files; binary files are assumed to be mostly *binary* rather than text, so things like indentation are non-issues to begin with.

Comment: And if you really need to have this, you can just `:setl et` again, hopefully aware of what you're doing.